# Push Notifications/Messaging in HTML5 web App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, push-notification

I am looking to integrate Push Notification in my Jquery mobile web App using PhoneGap for Android. Is there any solution to put cloud messaging in web app like push notification.
My app is based on getting friends location and checked in new location so i was looking for messaging or push notification in web app.

i am also read about http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

but this was not helpful for me.

If real time Push Notification not possible in HTML5 web app Please let me about asynchronous messaging like offline messaging in my app.

Comment: I know there is a possibility of WebSockets but can a web app emulate push notification features.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented realtime messaging with the WebSocket protocol, it is easy to implement, very performant and it supports encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Try Urban Airship. You get 1 million free push notifications every month.
It is also working with Phonegap.
Link: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

[ScaleDrone](https://www.scaledrone.com/) allows pushing to (and from) PhoneGap and web. It will use Websockets if possible and other technologies when Websockets are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-push-api-20141007/, but I wouldn't count on platform support here. However, since you are using PhoneGap, you can integrate your app with native cloud messaging. Here's [a tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/).

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification can be implemented. If you are using Phonegap, [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) ia a good available option. This plugin is for use with Cordova, and allows your application to receive push notifications on Amazon Fire OS, Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Windows8 devices. ALso it is free to use.

> The Android implementation uses Google's GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) service.

For detailed implementation guide using Android refer Android section in this [link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#manual_installation).

Hope it will answer your question. this is late answer here, can be helpful to you as well as others looking for similar kind of solution.